# How to retrieve a value from a form in PHP and use it in Fb.ui Publish to wall Function

Tags: php, facebook, fb.ui

I would like to make a facebook page tab with a form field, where visitors can fill in a value and then press a post to wall button where this value will be used in the name value of the fb.ui publish to wall function.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

This is what I use to post to wall.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: <APPID>,
              status: true,
              cookie: true,  
              xfbml: true});  };  
     (function() {
         var e = document.createElement('script');
         e.async = true;  
         e.src = document.location.protocol +  
         '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
         document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
     }());
 </script>

<script>
function publish_to_wall(){
   FB.ui({ 
     method: 'stream.publish',
     display: 'iframe',
     name: '<VALUE TO RETRIEVE FROM FORMFIELD> blablablalba',
     caption: '<TEXT>',
     link: 'http://www.facebook.com/<MYPAGE>',
     picture:'<IMAGE URL>'
   });
 }
</script>
```

To have a view on the tab you can check here: http://www.socialogika.com/tabs/hp/index.html

For now the formfield is still an image, and the share button is not active yet... But it gives you a better view what I mean to realise...

The Button should directly initiate the popup dialog.

Comment: google perhaps ? you havent showed any effort in this question so dont expect any effort in the answers

Comment: @ManseUK Offcourse I already have the script to publish to someones wall from within the app... The only thing is that I would like to have a form field where visitors can fill a value, then click on publish to wall, where this value will be used in the name value of the publish to wall script...

Comment: So your question really is "How to retrieve a value from a form in PHP ?"

Comment: @ManseUK yes that's correct...And obviously I know that, I just curious how to retrieve this value from the form field to be used in the popup dialog

Comment: How are you displaying the popup ? javascript ? jquery ? magic ? can you include some of your code so we have an idea of what you already have and what your are actually struggling / having problems with

Comment: @manseUk...Now that I gave all the info it might be clearer for you to answer the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the form an id... then use document.getElementById("theID").value , not really a facebook question though...

cheers

Extended example:

```
<input type='text' id='myText' />


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: <APPID>,
              status: true,
              cookie: true,  
              xfbml: true});  };  
     (function() {
         var e = document.createElement('script');
         e.async = true;  
         e.src = document.location.protocol +  
         '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
         document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
     }());
 </script>

<script>
function publish_to_wall(){
   FB.ui({ 
     method: 'stream.publish',
     display: 'iframe',
     name: document.getElementById('myText').value,
     caption: '<TEXT>',
     link: 'http://www.facebook.com/<MYPAGE>',
     picture:'<IMAGE URL>'
   });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: @miguel...Thanks for your answer.. could you please be some more specific..?

Comment: HI @miguel thanks for your extende example... Still one Question.. is it possible to fill in some more info on the name value... for example:  name: bla bla bla bla  document.getElementById('myText').value bla bla bla,

Comment: never mind allready got it: name: ('text ') + (document.getElementById('myText').value) +(' text')